# IHP - How to connect IHP's Postgres instance with Moodle?

Tags: postgresql, moodle, ihp

I'm trying to connect IHP's Postgres instance with Moodle. The [IHP Guide](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/database.html#connecting-to-db-via-terminal) uses `postgresql:///app?host=YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/build/db` with the development server running to connect however Moodle further requires Database host, name, user, password, port, Tables prefix and Unix Socket to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IHP uses a Postgres socket file to connect, the socket file is located at `YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/build/db/.s.PGSQL.5432`.
The database name is `app`, there is no password.
For example, with `psql` you can connect to the database as: `psql -h $PWD/build/db -d app`.

I'm not sure why are you trying to connect IHP with Moodle?
IHP dev server starts and restarts the Postgres database as you are developing, `./start` would start the database, and as soon as you exit, the database is stopped. However, it seems Moodle requires a database running forever in order to function.

Comment: Yes, Moodle requires Postgres to run. Can you please also tell what's the database user?

Comment: The user is either "postgres" or your current mac username (output of `echo $USER` in bash)